# pysimplegui ProgressBar update by a variable from a function

Tags: pysimplegui

I am using pysimplegui to design a progressbar for loading file process. The thing is I know how many rows to read a file, thus I want to update my progressbar based on the number of row during the loading. But it failed. Here is my relevant code.

First, I create a function to read my file.

```
n_species = 0  # counting for loading bar
def read_species(data_path):
    key_list = []  # total chemical formulas
    time_list = []  # total time serials
    global n_species

    with open(data_path) as f:
        # find time and chemical formula
        for i in f:
            if i[0] == '#':
                for j in i[1:].split():
                    j = sub(r'[\x00-\x00]', r'F', j)
                    if j not in key_list:
                        key_list.append(j)
            else:
                time_list.append(i.split()[0])
            n_species += 1
        # build total dict of time, chemical formula and its number
        var_list, dict_data = [], {
            i: {k: 0
                for k in time_list}
            for i in key_list
        }
        for i in f:
            if i[0] == '#':  # chemical list per timestep
                var_list.append(i[1:].split())
            else:  # number of chemicals per timestep
                var_list.append(i.split())
                for k, v in zip(*var_list):
                    k = sub(r'[\x00-\x00]', r'F', k)
                    if k == 'Timestep':
                        time = v
                        continue
                    dict_data[k][time] = v
                var_list.clear()
            n_species += 1
        del dict_data['Timestep']
    return {k: v for k, v in sorted(dict_data.items())}
```

You can see that I have a "n_species" variable to update the loading process. Then I want to use this changing value for sg.ProgressBar. Here is the relevant code.

```
[sg.Input(key='-INPUT-'), sg.FileBrowse(), sg.Button('Load')],
[sg.Text('Loading Progress'), sg.ProgressBar(4e6, orientation='h', size=(40, 10), key='-PROGRESS-')],

if event == 'Load':
    sg.popup_auto_close('Loading reaxff_out.species!', title='Loading', button_type=5)
    species = read_species(values['-INPUT-'])
    window['-PROGRESS-'].UpdateBar(n_species)
    window['-CHEMICALS-'].update(species.keys())
    sg.popup_auto_close('Loading Completed!', title='Loading', button_type=5)
```

But the progress bar is updated only after finishing the loading process.

I want my progress bar to be updated by some value from a function or any other code out of the "while true ..." pysimplegui structure. However, most answers I found on website is all about using a for loop which cannot be done here.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run your function `read_species` in thread, like `threading.Thread(target=read_species, args=(species,), daemon=True)`, and call `window.write_event_value(event, value)` in `read_species` to generate an event to update the progress bar for each step. Then add one case in the event loop to handle this event to update progressbar.

Comment: Tried and failed... I even tried with window.perform_long_operation, still not working.
Could you show me some examples on this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Refer https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Multithreaded_ProgressBar.py